# Multi-Threading IP Address Pings Causing Application Crash

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, ping

Boy, learning something new can be a real headache if you can't find a solid source. I have been designing applications in a linear fashion for some time now and want to step up into a more powerful approach. I have been reading up on threading, and perhaps have gone to an larger level than I should. However, one usually steps up when the application calls for it and no better time than the present to learn something new.

My program is designed to do something that seems rather simple, but has become extremely difficult to create in a smooth running manor. The original design created object of each device on the network it wished to ping, in my real world environment they are Kindles. The goal was to ensure they were still connected to the network by Pining them. I used a `For Loop` and `Obj Array` to do this set on a `Timer`. This had unexpected results causing the `ListView` to flicker and load slowly after the `ListView1.Items.Clear`. I evolved into updating the `List Items` rather than clearing them and the flicker remained.

I assumed this was due to the slow process of the array and pings so I started hunting for solutions and came across `Multi-Threading`. I have known about this for some time, but have yet to dive into the practice. My program seemed to need more speed and smoother operation so I took a stab at it. The below code in its complete form is the result, however it crashes and throws errors. Clearly I have not used Threading as it was intended. Using it in simpler functions works fine and I feel I have the grasp. That is if i want my program to pointlessly run counters.

I don't know what to do next in my steps for getting this task done, and figure I am combining several different methods into a mush of dead program. I could really use some help getting back on track with this. All comments welcome and thank you for checking out my code.

> Form1 Code

```
Public Class Form1

'Obj Array
Public Shared objDevice As New List(Of kDevice)
'Thread Array for each Obj
Public Shared thread() As System.Threading.Thread

Private Sub ipRefresh(objID, itemPos)

    Dim objDev As kDevice = objID

    If My.Computer.Network.Ping(objDev.kIP) Then
        objDev.kStatus = "Online"
        objDev.kPings = 0

    Else
        objDev.kPings += 1
    End If

    If objDev.kPings >= 8 Then
        objDev.kStatus = "Offline"
        objDev.kPings = 0
        ListView1.Items(itemPos).BackColor = Color.Red
    End If

    Dim str(4) As String
    Dim itm As ListViewItem
    str(0) = objDev.kName
    str(1) = objDev.kIP
    str(2) = objDev.kStatus
    str(3) = objDev.kPings
    itm = New ListViewItem(str)
    ListView1.Items(itemPos) = itm

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Me.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False

    ' Adding ListView Columns
    ListView1.Columns.Add("Device", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    ListView1.Columns.Add("IP Address", 150, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    ListView1.Columns.Add("Status", 60, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    ListView1.Columns.Add("Pings", 60, HorizontalAlignment.Left)

    Dim ipList As New List(Of String)
    Dim nameList As New List(Of String)

    Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("kDevices.csv")
        MyReader.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        MyReader.Delimiters = New String() {","}
        Dim currentRow As String()
        Dim rowP As Integer = 1
        While Not MyReader.EndOfData
            Try
                currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
                Dim cellP As Integer = 0
                Dim nTemp As String = ""

                For Each currentField As String In currentRow

                    Select Case cellP

                        Case 0
                            nameList.Add(currentField.Replace("""", ""))
                        Case 1
                            ipList.Add(currentField.Replace("""", ""))

                    End Select
                    cellP += 1

                Next
            Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
                MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message & " is invalid.  Skipping")
            End Try
            rowP += 1
        End While
    End Using

    Dim nameLAR As String() = nameList.ToArray
    Dim ipLAR As String() = ipList.ToArray

    ReDim Preserve thread(nameLAR.Length)

    For i As Integer = 0 To nameLAR.Length - 1

        Dim newDevice As New kDevice
        Dim objNum = i

        objDevice.Add(newDevice)

        newDevice.kName = nameLAR(i)
        newDevice.kIP = ipLAR(i)

        If My.Computer.Network.Ping(newDevice.kIP) Then
            newDevice.kStatus = "Online"
        Else
            newDevice.kStatus = "Loading"
        End If

        Dim str(4) As String
        Dim itm As ListViewItem
        str(0) = newDevice.kName
        str(1) = newDevice.kIP
        str(2) = newDevice.kStatus
        str(3) = newDevice.kPings
        itm = New ListViewItem(str)
        If newDevice.kStatus = "Loading" Then
            itm.BackColor = Color.Yellow
        End If
        ListView1.Items.Add(itm)

        thread(objNum) = New System.Threading.Thread(Sub() Me.ipRefresh(objDevice(objNum), objNum))

    Next

End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    For i As Integer = 0 To objDevice.Count - 1

        thread(i).Start()

    Next

End Sub

End Class
```

> kDevice Class

```
Public Class kDevice

Private strkName As String
Private strkIP As String
Private strkStatus As String
Private strkLastStatus As String
Private strkPings As Integer = 0

Public Property kName As String

    Get
        Return strkName
    End Get

    Set(value As String)
        strkName = value
    End Set

End Property

Public Property kIP As String

    Get
        Return strkIP
    End Get

    Set(value As String)
        strkIP = value
    End Set

End Property

Public Property kStatus As String

    Get
        Return strkStatus
    End Get

    Set(value As String)
        strkStatus = value
    End Set

End Property

Public Property kPings As Integer

    Get
        Return strkPings
    End Get

    Set(value As Integer)
        strkPings = value
    End Set

End Property

End Class
```

> The Error / Crash on Line 32 of my code which is when it tries to pass the update to the ListView Item

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException'
occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: InvalidArgument=Value of '18'
is not valid for 'index'.
```

or

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' 
occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance
of an object.
```

If my code does not make sense, or at lease the idea of what I was trying to make it do, please let me know and I will explain whichever parts are unclear. Again thank you for looking over my issue.

Comment: You should add information about *how* it crashes. What error message, do you get a dump, etc etc.

Comment: I just added it. I used to get dumps when I was doing the original method of clearing the Items from the List View. Blue Screened out. That has not happened since I witched to the Treading attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Just a possible issue I noticed:

```
Dim str(4) As String
    Dim itm As ListViewItem
    str(0) = newDevice.kName
    str(1) = newDevice.kIP
    str(2) = newDevice.kStatus
    str(3) = newDevice.kPings
    itm = New ListViewItem(str)
    If newDevice.kStatus = "Loading" Then
        itm.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    End If
    ListView1.Items.Add(itm)
```

In this bit here, you declare str(4) which would be 5 possible indexes (remember it starts at zero), where you should have 4 (str(3)) . I don't think this is the whole issue, but just a small bit you should probably fix. You also may want to look into other ways to update the listview without setting

```
Me.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
```

Here's an awesome guide that helped me when I did my first multi threaded application: http://checktechno.blogspot.com/2012/11/multi-thread-for-newbies.html

Comment: Thank you, I goofed that up. I always found confusion in the assignment of the preset array length. I know it starts from zero, but it would seem more logical for the assignment part to be the length. haha Thank you for the tutorial! I will check it out!

Comment: Would you mind emailing me the solution? I'd love to dig into it more, but I didn't really want to have to recreate the entire program. I actually made a similar project a few months back, but not nearly as in depth. stefankelsey gmail. Fill in the blanks

Comment: absolutely, you will just have to create a kDevices.csv in the root and populate your own IPs! Is there email functionality here or do I need to get your address?

Comment: Its stefankelsey at gmail

Comment: I zipped it, but Gmail does not like the file. Blocked for security reasons. Is there a format that would be better to send it in?

Comment: zip it, change the extension to something else. IE : solution.zip -> solution.ziperish

Comment: Sent. I thought about that, but one time it corrupted the file on download. Let me know if it works! Thank you for taking the time to look at it.

Comment: I copy pasted your email from the comment. Replaced `at` with `@`.

Comment: What is your email? I'll confirm you have the correct one by sending you a blank email

Comment: ryanbrown8384 at gmail

Comment: Got it, and sent back.